# Sidebar with elements at the bottom over other elements

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a sidebar similar to this one:

http://jsfiddle.net/pf798/

```
<ul id="top-elements"></ul>
<ul id="bottom-elements"></ul>
```

with two lists. One for the top elements and another for the bottom elements with an absolute position.

What I need is to have at least to elements at the bottom of this sidebar without strange behaviours such as: when resizing the window, lets says to half of the height, the bottom elements will be on top of the "top elements". How can I have the bottom elements to stop when I resize the window height and they reach to the top elements?

Answer (score -2):

Just remove the absolute position from the second list. It will still be at the bottom, so there is no need to absolutely position it there.